# How can I print different scatter plots in a For loop in pandas?

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib, 3d, scatter-plot

I am trying to plot the 3D scatter plots in different rows using python.

The array "seasons" contains four different datasets and I am trying to call each dataset and plot 3D scatter plot separately.

This below code gives me only a result of one dataset seasons[df].

```
seasons = [summer_spike_df,Autumn_spike_df,Winter_spike_df,Spring_spike_df]
colors = ['b', 'orange', 'g', 'r', 'c', 'm', 'y', 'k', 'Brown', 'ForestGreen'] 
ncenters = 3

for df in (seasons):
    alldata = np.vstack((df['time_of_day'], df['Height'],df['resolution']))
    cntr, u, u0, d, jm, p, fpc = fuzz.cluster.cmeans(
        alldata, ncenters, 3, error=0.005, maxiter=1000, init=None)
    fpcs = []
    fpcs.append(fpc)
    for pt in cntr:
        ax.scatter(pt[0], pt[1],pt[2],color='r')

    cluster_membership = np.argmax(u, axis=0)
    for j in range(ncenters):
        ax.scatter(df['time_of_day'][cluster_membership == j],
                df['Height'][cluster_membership == j],
                df['resolution'][cluster_membership == j],
                '.', 
                color=colors[j], edgecolor='k',marker='o', s=20, lw=0, alpha=0.7)

ax.set_title('Centers = {0}; FPC = {1:.2f}'.format(ncenters, fpc))
ax.axis('on')
#ax.set_ylim([0,6])
ax.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image]

If I put the `plt.show()` and `plt.close()` outside of the for loop then it shows all scatter in the same plot.

Answer (score 0):

You don't show where you define `ax`. However, to get your datasets into separate 3d scatter plots, you will need to define them in separate Axes.

For instance, you can define 4 separate Axes in one Figure and explicitly plot each dataframe into separate Axes:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)
for df, ax in zip(seasons, axes.flatten()):
    # Your for loop will probably work as is here
    ...

    # With this exception, you'll just move code below within for loop
    ax.set_title('Centers = {0}; FPC = {1:.2f}'.format(ncenters, fpc))
    ax.axis('on')
    ax.grid()
```